# Traverse Iframe using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have html structure like this. I want to get the second table that has no class or id. How would I get the second table from the `iframe`?

```
<iframe>
<html>
<body>
    <table><table>
    <table>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I am trying like this

```
Elements iframe = doc.select("iframe");

for(Element e : iframe) {
    System.out.println(e.child(0));     
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is that the real `html` you're trying to parse? Because it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want to traverse the `iframe` element? It is better to get the content from `iframe` source 
like

```
Element iframe = doc.select("iframe").first();
String iframeSrc = iframe.attr("src");

if(iframeSrc != null) {
    iframeContentDoc = Jsoup.connect(iframeSrc).get();
}
```

You can do this way only.

Comment: This tries to connect to the src address, but it does change the values inside the iframe. Like the keys, Tokens,etc... `that's not useful`.