# Unable to parse webpage with frameset

Tags: groovy, jsoup

I'm trying to parse Groovydoc, but Jsoup doesn't find the frameset in which everything is contained.

```
        Connection connection=Jsoup.connect('http://groovy-lang.org/api.html')
        Document document=connection.get()
        Elements element= document.getElementsByTag('frameset')
        element.each {println(it)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the result that is returned by `connection.get()` you can see that there is no `frameset` tag:

```
println document
```

Now, if you open the site in a browser and use development tools to look at it's html code you can see that the `frameset` you are looking for is a child of an `iframe` from source `http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi`.

Just load the `iframe` url with Jsoup to get the `frameset`

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect('http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi')
Document document = connection.get()
Elements element = document.getElementsByTag('frameset')
element.each { println it }
```

Or if you do not want to hardcode the `iframe` source url to parse, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16236780/1107608) SO answer on how to get the source url