# jsoup returns "browser does not support iframes"

Tags: html, http, iframe, jsoup, user-agent

I'd like to retrieve content from an iframe via jsoup but get the following error message: "your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames ..."

Code:

```
Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent(USER_AGENT).get().getElementById(ID);
```

I have also tried using java.net.URLConnection and Apache HttpClient. I suppose there is something wrong with the user agent which is currently

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87 Safari/537.36
```

but no clue how to fix this ...

Answer (score -1):

I can't test right now, but you may try to set the UserAgent in Jsoup to a string of a known browser that supports iframes.

see [JSoup UserAgent, how to set it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581655/jsoup-useragent-how-to-set-it-right)

Or try to get the source of the iframe directly, as explained in this SO [Traverse Iframe using jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234019/traverse-iframe-using-jsoup)

Comment: Would the negative voter explain why my answer is bad?